# Import dashboard with Helm using Sidecar for dashboards

Tags: grafana, kubernetes-helm

I've exported a Grafana Dashboard (output is a `json` file) and now I would like to import it when I install Grafana (all automatic, with Helm and Kubernetes)

I just red [this](https://medium.com/@chris_linguine/how-to-monitor-your-kubernetes-cluster-with-prometheus-and-grafana-2d5704187fc8) post about how to add a `datasource` which uses the `sidecar` setup. In short, you need to create a values.yaml with

```
sidecar:
  image: xuxinkun/k8s-sidecar:0.0.7
  imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
  datasources:
    enabled: true
    label: grafana_datasource
```

And a ConfigMap which matches that label

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: prometheus-grafana-datasource
  labels:
    grafana_datasource: '1'
data:
  datasource.yaml: |-
    apiVersion: 1
    datasources:
    - name: Prometheus
      type: prometheus
      access: proxy
      orgId: 1
      url: http://source-prometheus-server
```

Ok, this works, so I tried to do something similar for bashboards, so I updated the values.yaml

```
sidecar:
  image: xuxinkun/k8s-sidecar:0.0.7
  imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
  dashboards:
    enabled: false
    # label that the configmaps with dashboards are marked with
    label: grafana_dashboard
  datasources:
    enabled: true
    label: grafana_datasource
```

And the ConfigMap

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: prometheus-grafana-dashboards
  labels:
    grafana_dashboard: '1'
data:
  custom-dashboards.json: |-
    {
      "annotations": {
        "list": [
          {
    ...
```

However when I install grafana this time and login, there are no dashboards
Any suggestions what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Any error in the logs?

Comment: I figured it out, thanks to [this](https://medium.com/@chris_linguine/how-to-monitor-your-kubernetes-cluster-with-prometheus-and-grafana-2d5704187fc8) post

Answer (score 2):

```
sidecar:
  image: xuxinkun/k8s-sidecar:0.0.7
  imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
  dashboards:
    enabled: false
    # label that the configmaps with dashboards are marked with
    label: grafana_dashboard
  datasources:
    enabled: true
    label: grafana_datasource
```

In the above code there should be `dashboard.enabled: true` to get dashboard enabled.

Comment: may I get any link to create / import custom grafana dashboard using helm?
Note: I'm just trying to add one more dashboard in the existing grafana using helmfile